# How to update multiple rows of a table in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.5

Helper,

I wanna update multiple addresses for a particular user_id, with out changing its existing order. Also I'm using relation here.

```
public function update(Request $request, $id){
$data['id'] = $id;
$user = User::with('addresses')->find($id);

$j = $user['addresses'][0]['id'];

foreach($request->address_id as $key => $i){
    $i++;
}

foreach($request->address1 as $key => $v){
        if($j<$i){
            $user->addresses()->whereUserId($data['id'])->update([
                'address1' => $v,
                'address2' => $request->address2[$key],
                'state' => $request->state[$key],
                'country' => $request->country[$key]
            ]);
        }
    $j++;}
}
```

I'm getting input somewhat like this,

```
{"_method":"PATCH","address_id":["92","93"],"address1":["aaa","xxx"],"address2":["bbb","yyy"],"state":["ccc","zzz"],"country":["India","India"]}
```

When I do my update the last input, which means, `xxx,yyy,zzz,India` is getting update for both rows`92,93`

Comment: Your `$data` is not defined